# Django celery and rabbitmq doesn't work until restart

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I have problem with django, celery and rabbitmq.

I use celery to send messages to FCM devices, but problem is that celery doesn't run that FCM command for sending messages, until I restart celery server.

And when I restart celery, and try again, still same, I need to restart it again after every action.

Example code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from celery import shared_task
# firebase cloud messaging
from fcm.utils import get_device_model
Device = get_device_model()


@shared_task
def send_firebase_message(json, **kwargs):
    response = Device.send_msg(json, **kwargs)
    return response
```

This is simple code, so this `Device.send_msg` doesn't fire until I restart celery server.
So, celery doesn't do this task until i restart it. Maybe it is rabbitmq problem?

Anyone got any solution for this? What can be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like you need to clean Celery after every use. Try something like this:  ***$celery purge***

Comment: But that is bad if I need to do it for every action?

Comment: Doubt it. I call garbage collection in all my projects. especially when I use components. Otherwise things get stuck in RAM, create memory leaks, or like in your case, block processes.  Even if it is not the issue, Its a good practice

Comment: See here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149074/deleting-all-pending-tasks-in-celery-rabbitmq

Answer (score 0):

The --autoreload not working since 3.1, change to non-blocking inotify neededl

if you want know more refer the doc [deprecated](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1658)

we have another option do this , refer this post [auto reload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43929298/7261317).It seems working for my current projects

Comment: But i don't have problem with autoreload, celery is not working until i restart server, i don't change code, just add task to celery and it doesn't fire until restart.